# Java Word-counting Program w/ User-Defined String Variable

Tags: java, string, variables

To preface, I'm quite new to Java.

I have been trying to figure out what's going on with the following code -- I'm trying to find the number of spaces in the input (String s), but whenever the input is used as a variable it doesn't transfer over.  However a set string value does work, i.e:

```
String s = ("Happy days for all."); // Outputs "Spaces = 3"
```

I've read up a bit about why this could be but I cannot find a definitive answer on how to solve it.  Any suggestions?

```
import java.util.Scanner;
class Main {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print("Type a sentence > ");
    String s = input.next();

    long spaces = s.replaceAll("[^ ]", "").length();
    System.out.print("Spaces = " + spaces);
  } 
}
```

Input

```
Happy days for all.
```

Output:

```
Spaces = 0
```

Comment: Use `nextLine()` instead of `next()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`next()` will return the next complete token from this scanner.
If your input is `Happy days for all.` it will return `Happy` with the first call, `days` with the second one, `for` with the third and `all.` with the last.

If you want to get the complete sentence at once you need to use `nextLine()`.

Comment: Oh wow - that makes me look so much worse than I could've imagined.  Thanks for the quick response and clarification.  Luckily it's quite the quick fix!  Haha.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the line:
String s = input.next();

input.next() will return the input up to a delimiter, and in this case, a space.
And so s == "Happy"

Replace input.next() with input.nextLine();

Comment: Thank you as well for your quick and clear response!